# Method syntax in Object C

Tags: objective-c, syntax, methods

Can anyone explain method declaration syntax below for me? I can not understand the portion "connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection" next to "(void)"

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 -                             // method type. - is instance method, + is class method
 (void)                        // return type
 connection:                   // method name
 (NSURLConnection *)connection // first argument and its type
 didReceiveResponse:           // method name continues
 (NSURLResponse *)response     // second argument and its type
```

But you should probably find a book and actually learn Obj-C. If you don't understand the syntax, you have a long way to go.

Comment: You should put the - on a separate line, "this is an instance method."

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

1. void is the return type;
2. the method takes a first argument called `connection` of type `NSURLConnection*`;
3. the method takes a second argument called `response` of type `NSURLResponse*`.

It is a different way to write the method signature. It helps if you think of it as:

```
- (void)connection:didReceiveResponse:
```

The thing which is very characteristic of Obj-C (vs. C or C++) is the fact that arguments are intermixed within the signature. The advantage of doing this is that you can easily give a name to each argument in a call to the method:

```
[connection:currentConnection didReceiveResponse:lastResponse];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its standard in delegate callbacks in Cocoa to pass the originating object, in this case the NSURLConnection which has received a response.

If you don't understand the method syntax in general, then probably read up on objective c, and see the other answers here